# Unsolved uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Prove or disprove that: the function $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ defined by $ f(x) := x^{1/3} \log (1+|x|)$ is uniform continuous!

I have tried all possible (I THINK) to prove it to be uniform continuous but failed. I think it would be NOT uniform continuous!Now, here I am still unable to find suitable sequences having their distance going to zero, BUT the distance between their functional images converging to some non-zero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Prove that its derivative is bounded.

Comment: I had already computed the derivative.... letting $x$ goes to infinity, in spite of using L'hospital's rule several times nothing fruitful happened though!! Is it really bounded??

Comment: To prove $\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{2/3}} \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$ you need to use l'Hospital's rule just once.